# I want my django rest framework serializer to accept input but not add to model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I removed some fields from my model, but I want the serializer to still accept the fields as input.  How do I have fields the serializer accepts but doesn't use?

```
class EventBaseSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Event
        fields = ("id", "name")

        #unused_fields = ("last_name")
```

Comment: You can exgtends serializers.Serializer instead of ModelSerializer. I believe it's more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

> You can add extra fields to a ModelSerializer or override the default
>   fields by declaring fields on the class, just as you would for a
>   Serializer class.

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.CharField(source='get_absolute_url', read_only=True)
    groups = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)`

    class Meta:
        model = Account
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a field to be used for input but not output, you'll need to add this field to the `fields` list and mark it as [`write_only`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#write_only) likely with [`extra_kwargs`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I want to get data other than the model has and use them in the serializer methods for something else. But the default "create" method of the serializer try to create the object using those foreign fields too and should give an error like:

> Got a `TypeError` when calling `MyModel.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `MyModel.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the MyModelCreateSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.

I fixed the issue by popping them from the serializer's data after using them as I want and everything continued just fine.

```
class MyModelCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foreign_input_1 = serializers.DateField(write_only=True)
    foreign_input_2 = serializers.DateField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate(self, data):
        MySecondModel.objects.create(foreign_input_1=data.pop('foreign_input_1'),
                                     foreign_input_1=data.pop('foreign_input_2'))
        return data
```

Don't forget to use the `write_only=True` parameter on the foreign fields. The serializer will try to read them from the object in any data return operation, like returning the value of the created object.